# Mails are not sending from my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending emails from my Laravel project. In the localhost it works perfectly but after makes the site live it gives the following error.

```
The connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com:stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`whm001.smart1marketing.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.googlemail.com'
```

I am using same google configuration settings in which I used in Laravel , I have tried clearing all caches, etc. but no solution

Following is .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@smart1leads.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='LifeLoveAndOtherThings'
```

Comment: In .env file is all setting right? (can you post config?)

Comment: Yes all settings are right,same as i used in loclhost

Comment: Can you post on your question env file config?

Comment: Sure, i have posted

Comment: have you installed and configured SMTP ?

Comment: yes mail is already configured in gmail app settings, and its working in localhost. But in live i didint installed anything

Comment: Change your `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@smart1leads.com` to a real email address and try again

Comment: @TalhaF. mail id is live